# How to Setting Connection using an instance in "Data Source" in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

Just trying to use System.Data.SqlConnection. work fine before, but when I use Data Source using an instance xx_xxx I get an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)'

Here is my code before:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=00.00.00.01;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xx;Password=Pxxxxxxxxx2");
conn.Open();
```

after I add instance in Data Source and get error:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=00.00.00.01\\xx_xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xx;Password=Pxxxxxxxxx2");
conn.Open();
```

I use .Net Core ver 3.0.100-preview8-013656, 
Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview ver 16.3.0 Preview 2.0,
and SQL Server 2005

Comment: Is the name of the instance correct? Is the service of the instance up and running? Can you connect to the instance in Management Studio?

Comment: it could be a port number as well. normally if you have multiple sql instances on the same server, it always is a port issue. you may need to specify a port like this 00.00.00.01\\xx_xxx, 1433;

Comment: yes I've tried in Management studio and work fine.

Comment: @Baahubali thanks for help. but still get same error. I tried same thing with SQL 2017 and it work. any explanation or solution?

Comment: what port number did you try?

Comment: @Baahubali I does not set the port in DB. so I assume the port is default, and I use 1433 as default

Comment: Instance name will use dynamic port, so you cannot use default port number (1433).You need to check the port number and change it to 1433.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all help, I don't know how or why. but I find solution by using linked server from Sql Server 2017 to my target Database (Sql Server 2005)